# Wordpress blog not showing on blog page

Tags: wordpress, blogs, posts

I have specified a page in settings to become the blog part of my site, where my posts should appear.

When I click on "Blog" it just shows me anything that I've recently added to my homepage for some reason.

If I click on the "recent posts" links at the bottom of any page it takes me to the blog page, which is what I want but it doesn't take me to that same blog page when I click on the "Blog" Link at the top of my page in the menu bar.

I have already deleted the blog page and started again with setting up a new blog page that should be where my posts appear, but that didn't work.

I am using "Widley" Theme, just a free one I downloaded.

my website is http://www.interior-architecture.co/

Comment: Screenshots, code snippets would be useful.

Comment: as Tibbers said, plus also what theme you are using? url to your site?

Comment: Give some screenshot or give your page url...

Comment: Okay, I've added url to my site and theme

Comment: I have no idea what a code snippet is! sorry.

Comment: A code snippet is when you copy and paste your code into your post and then format it using the code snippet button.

Comment: You are being dowe voted as you need to make your question clearer by the use of formatting. Split the question into sections. A background section and then the actual question in bold. Then some code to show everyone what is actaully going on.

Comment: feels a bit off-topic

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the two pages you have mentioned "home" in the menu and "blog" on the left widget bar are two different pages. You need to make them both link to the same page.